# Windows freezing withTPL

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

After I clicked the "Start" button in WPF, the program went to TPL part. The main window was freezing then.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var producer = Producer();
    var consumer = Consumer();
    Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
}
 async Task Producer()
    {
        try
        {
              // add items to the queue
  async Task Consumer()
    {
        try
        {
            var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                //TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(),
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            };
            var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<AppointmentReminder>(
          r=>
          {
               string s = RunScript(r);
               Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
               {
                   slider.Value = slider.Value - 1; // update the slider value;
               }); 


          },executionDataflowBlockOptions);
            // m_Queue is bufferBlock 
            m_Queue.LinkTo(
            consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
```

Questions:

1. How to deal with the window freezing? If I uncomment out `TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, it is still freezing and the customer part is never reached.
2. I want to update the slider by `slider.Value = slider.Value - 1;` it failed as well.

Comment: You should format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.WaitAll` waits synchronously while blocking the calling thread. In your case that would block the GUI thread "freezing" your windows and may even lead to a deadlock.

Use `await Task.WhenAll` in an `async void` event handler (the only case where `async void` is acceptable) to asynchronously wait without blocking a thread:

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var producer = Producer();
    var consumer = Consumer();

    await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
}
```

Comment: @Love **`WhenAll`**. not `WaitAll`.